# Horrible Open Rate on our First Civi bulk mail!

Tags: spam

One of our lists is our most loyal followers. This list is composed of people who have not only opted to be on this list but who look forward to our alerts and have historically been very responsive to our alerts. We migrated our lists from Vertical Response to CiviCRM and were excitedly awaiting for a good response to our recent bulk mail. Disappointingly, out of 500+ recipients, we experienced an 8% open rate, a historic low, yet I know that the vast majority of people on this list are eager from news from us. Could this be a spam filter problem? I have only one image in this bulk email and I can't see any red flags in the subject heading that would trigger spam filters. How do I work with Google and other spam filters and help our constituents get our email?

Comment: Hi Sarah, welcome to CiviCRM. Can you share a bit more about your CiviCRM install mailing set up. Is this a brand new CiviCRM install an existing install. Have you sent much email via CiviCRM prior to the list migration? Are you sending your email using a service mailgun CiviSMTP etc, or via SMTP or off the server (which is the default setting)?  Have you set up SPF, DKIM and DMARC?

Comment: You can find your outbound mail settings at Admin Menu -> Administer -> System Settings -> Outbound mail . For extensions have a look at the Extensions menu that should be on the same menu. If you are using a recent version of CiviCRM you should be able to just click on the CiviCRM triangle logo on the Admin Menu and type the relevant menu item to go straight to it.

Comment: Try using mail-tester.com to test the spamyness etc of your emails.  This will tell you whether SPF, DMARC and DKIM are set up.  Send it a copy of the bulk email where you got a low response and see what it says.  You should be looking for 8/10 or higher although even that is no guarantee of delivery if you're running on a shared host.

Comment: Wow, I don't know the answer to these questions so I will cut and paste them in an email to someone who can. Thanks for the quick response time!